# Executable path is not absolute

Tags: linux, systemd

I am trying to apply DRY by utilizing env vars as below:

```
Environment='SHARED=/var/www/backend/shared/'
Environment='QUEUE=critical'
Environment='BUNDLE_PATH=/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/bundle'

ExecStart=${BUNDLE_PATH} exec sidekiq -q {$QUEUE} --index 0 --pidfile ${SHARED}tmp/pids/sidekiq_reserved_${QUEUE}.pid -e production --logfile ${SHARED}log/sidekiq_reserved_${QUEUE}.log --config ${SHARED}config/sidekiq_${QUEUE}.yml --daemon
```

However, I got error:

```
[/lib/systemd/system/sidekiq.service:30] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: ${BUNDLE_PATH} exec sidekiq -q {$QUEUE} --index 0 --pidfile ${SHARED}tmp/pids/sidekiq_reserved_${QUEUE}.pid -e production --logfile ${SHARED}log/sidekiq_reserved_${QUEUE}.log --config ${SHARED}config/sidekiq_${QUEUE}.yml --daemon
sidekiq.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
sidekiq.service: Failed to create sidekiq.service/start: Unit sidekiq.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
```

So, is this a problem of how I substituted the env vars? 
Any idea?

Comment: Did you check whenever sidekiq allows for variables to be used or how you'd need to use them? It's also kind of unclear where you but what and where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a variable as the command. You can work around it by starting a shell first or just hardcoding the path to the executable.

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '${BUNDLE_PATH} sidekiq -q {$QUEUE} ...'
```

I was curious and looks like they're thinking about adding this:

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1274

So go like that issue, seems useful to me!

Comment: thanks, but if you notice the value of `BUNDLE_PATH ` it already has the app that will that will execute, if I substitute the env vars manually, the ExecStart above will work with not issue..

Comment: @HoD: Note that the command in OP's case would actually be `bundle exec`, not just `exec`.